Does cublas perform a real transpose operation during execution gemm api (such as non-linear reading or transposing into LDS)?
I know that executing a standalone transpose operation in CUDA is expensive, so I'm curious: What is the meaning of the cublasOperation_t parameter in the cublas gemm API? Does cublas perform a real transpose operation during execution (such as non-linear reading or transposing into LDS)? Or does this parameter simply indicate the layout of the data in memory?
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-t-gemm
I just read the documents and don't know how to prove it

The parameter indicates whether CUBLAS will read the data in column major or row major order ("transpose") order.

An optimized matrix multiplication loads small blocks of the input matrices into shared memory for fast, repeated access. This is when the data may be transposed or conjugated. The temporary storage layout may differ, though. Matrices are column-major but for the left side of the multiplication you need row-wise access. Defining that the left should be transposed actually saves a transposition in this loading step since the left matrix already has the proper layout.
